# What is the logic behind the syntax used for the "calculations" code?

Tags: cognito-forms

The Basic Editor doesn't seem sufficient for what I need to do. I've had some success with the Advanced Editor, but I'm still not 100% on the distinction between brackets, periods and quotations.

Could you fill me in?

Answer (score 0):

Calculations in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) are extremely powerful and go way beyond the basic math supported by most form builders.  The syntax is that of modern object-oriented languages, loosely based off of C# and VB.NET with just a touch of JavaScript-style implicit magic to make things easy.

However, even with our autocomplete capability and detailed error messages, it is still at its heart actually real code, so I definitely understand when people need help getting the hang of it.

The best place to start is with our Calculations Overview:
https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/2/calculations

Specific to your question, here is some feedback:

- Always start calculations with an equals sign "=", similar to Excel
- Fields and Sections are referenced by simply typing their name (without spaces or special characters).
- Access child fields on complex information (like Sections, Names, Addresses) by typing a "." after these fields and then selecting the child fields, like Name.First
- Call methods/functions on things like dates, text, repeating sections, etc. by typing a "." after fields of these types and then selecting the methods/functions to call and specifying parameter values in (), such as Registrants.Sum(RegistrationFee).
- Enter literal/constant text values or dates by putting them in "quotes", like "12/15/2015".  This is especially important for choice fields, where the choice values are text and must appear as quoted text for comparison.

Feel free to submit a support request if you have specific questions for your forms.